# How to insert the default user into a filepath python

Tags: python, default, filepath

I have a code that makes a folder:

```
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\Documents\\Myfiles):
     os.chdir('C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\Documents')
     os.mkdir('Myfiles')
```

I want this to be able to run on any computer, so how can I get the default user without asking and doing something like:

```
DefaultUser = input('What is the default user for this PC?: ')
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\' + DefaultUser + '\\Documents\\Myfiles'):
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\' + DefaultUser + '\\Documents')
    os.mkdir('Myfiles')
```

**EDIT: By default user, I mean the one currently running the program.**

Comment: Can't you just use `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`?

Comment: You can use [Path.home()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home) from pathlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following to first get the username using `getpass` and then use it in the path using a placeholder `%s`. I tried it on my Mac and it returned the correct username.

```
import getpass
Name = getpass.getuser()
print (Name) # To confirm that it gives the correct username

if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\%s\\Documents\\Myfiles' %Name):
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\%s\\Documents' %Name)
    os.mkdir('Myfiles')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `os`, make use of the `expanduser()` method in `path`:

```
import os
curdir = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')
# 'C:\\Users\\me/Documents'
newdir = 'Myfiles'
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(curdir, newdir)):
    os.chdir(curdir)
    os.mkdir(newdir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer is about the process owner

```
import os
import psutil

# get the PID
pid = os.getpid()

# get the username
username = psutil.Process(pid).username
```

Untested, but should work on Windows and Linux